# В чём отличие SortedSet, SortedDictionary и SortedList в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Как я понимаю, все эти коллекции являются реализацией ассоциативного массива. Но я не особо понимаю в чём между ними разница. Везде можно хранить пары ключ-значение в отсортированном виде, единственное что я понял что в их основе лежат разные структуры данных, но практические отличия мне не понятны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, SortedSet - это не словарь, а множество. Этот тип не реализует IDictionary, а реализует ISet. С точки зрения api, можно составить, так сказать, пропорцию: SortedSet так же относится к SortedDictionary, как HashSet относится к Dictionary.

Зачем вообще **SortedSet и SortedDictionary** нужны? **Они нужны если вам важен порядок перечисления элементов.** В теории, с деревьями, которые там внутри, можно сделать много интересных вещей, но SortedSet и SortedDictionary этого делать не позволяют; так что если вам нужно именно дерево - в сторону Sorted-коллекций даже не смотрите.

Теперь **SortedList**. SortedList - это такая странная реализация IDictionary, которая неплохо работает на чтение (быстрее чем SortedDictionary, но всё ещё медленнее Dictionary), но крайне медленна при изменениях. В принципе, этого было бы достаточно чтобы вообще никогда её не использовать, но у неё есть одно достоинство: **крайняя компактность по памяти**. Там внутри массив ключей, массив значений и несколько служебных полей, всё!

Применений у SortedList два. Во-первых, если вам нужен словарь из малого числа элементов - SortedList прекрасно подойдёт. Во-вторых, если вам нужен компактный неизменяемый словарь - SortedList тоже сработает, только не забудьте упорядочить содержимое *перед* укладыванием в SortedList, и следить за неизменяемостью вам придётся тоже самому.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы понять, когда использовать SotedSet, SortedDictionary или SortedList, сначала рассмотрим, когда вообще нужны SortedX, а не обычный Dictionary.

Dicitonary даёт вставку за O(1), удаление за O(1), и взятие элемента по ключу, тоже за O(1). Что ещё нужно для счастья? Ну например вернуть ключи-значения отсортированными по ключу. Dictionary сам не умеет, поэтому во-первых придётся потратить дополнительную память, чтобы выполнить эту сортировку. И сама сортировка обойдётся в O(n*log(n)).

Так вот, SortedX сделают это за O(n) и почти без дополнительной памяти. Причём SortedList должен справится даже быстрее SortedDictionary(SortedSet), так как он основан на массиве, а с ними процессоры работают быстрее, чем с деревьями, на которых основан второй.

Но дело в том что за это преимущество вы возможно уже заплатили при вставке. Если вставлять не все элементы сразу в SortedX, а по одному, то суммарно вставки обойдутся:

- Dictionary `O(n)`
- SortedDictionary `O(n*log(n))`
- SortedList `O(n*n)`

Отсюда вывод по выбору:

- вставки случаются часто, а сортированный перебор редко - Dictionary
- и вставки часто и сортированные переборы тоже - SortedDictionary
- вставки редко, а сортированные переборы часто - SortedList

---

Теперь что такое `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Это такая обёртка над `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, но многие возможности кастрированы. Благо, можно вернуть себе отрезанные возможности, достаточно просто использовать второй вместо первого и позаимствовать код [KeyValuePairComparer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedDictionary.cs#L844) из SortedDictionary. Суть компаратора проста - для сравнений используем дефолтный компаратор по типу ключа и сравниваем только ключи.

---

С чем ещё плохо справляется стандартный Dictionary? Он бесполезен при поиске по диапазону значений. Придётся сделать полный перебор O(n).

SortedDictinary тут бессилен только из-за интерфейса.

SortedList отлично подойдёт, если границы диапазона это ключи.
O(log(n)) на найти границы, и O(m) на перебрать диапазон, где m - число вхождений в диапазоне.
Если же границы, это не ключи, то можно уложиться в ту же сложность, но встроенных интерфейсов для этого нет.

SortedSet изначально имеет метод на получение подмножества по произвольному диапазону - GetViewBetween. SortedSet<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> с компаратором тоже позволит пользоваться этой фичей. Сложность плюс-минус такая же, как у SortedList.

---

Ещё Dictionary не умеет выдавать максимальный-минимальны элемент без полного перебора O(n). SortedSet и SortedList смогут за O(1). SortedDictionary - мог бы, но спасибо разработчикам, они похоже хотели скрыть, что там дерево, и спрятали эти возможности так же.